# Running a java program through command line

Tags: java, jar, javac

I am running a Java program with the following command:

```
java -cp .:./* com.bot.fix.botclient
```

All the jar files are in the same directory. It works FINE! But what if I want to run it from a different folder?

The full location of the java program is: FIX/fixprog/src/com/fix/botclient

But if I try to run:

```
java -cp FIX/fixprog/src/* FIX/fixprog/src/com.bot.fix.botclient
```

I get:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class FIX.fixprog.src.com.bot.fix.botclient
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I run the same Java program but not in the same directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only jar files try:

```
java -cp FIX/fixprog/src/* com.bot.fix.botclient
```

If you have also classes you should try:

```
java -cp FIX/fixprog/src/*:FIX/fixprog/src/ com.bot.fix.botclient
```

If both did not work perhaps you shoud use absolut path with disk unit if you are using windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try if below works. You don't need to specify path when giving the fully qualified name of your java class that you are trying to execute. The "cp" part takes care of it.

`java -cp FIX/fixprog/src com.bot.fix.botclient`

Comment: I get an error when trying to run it like that. Actually I get a bunch of errors related to the jar files, so I think that the jar files in the src directory aren't being run.